# "I can design a building of any kind of difficulty level" - looking for a more natural ending to the sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

> I can design a building of any kind of difficulty level.

The sentence came out quite weird. I tried to say that I can design any building, no matter how difficult it's going to be. How to correct it?

Comment: Are you asking about:  The complexity of the building?  The difficulty of constructing the building? The difficulty of the design process?  The number of regulatory constraints on the building design?  Were you trained as an architect (or building designer) in a system where each year, you were expected to design more "difficult" buildings than in the previous year?

Comment: I think you already did: _I can design any building, no matter how difficult it's going to be._ That's a pretty good wording right there.

Comment: @J.R. - He tries to keep the sentence in the Russian official register: "Я могу спроектировать здание **любого уровня сложности**" (any difficulty level) - a typical phrase for a business resume or some other document that he put into English, cookie-cutter style. "No matter how difficult it is going to be" is probably a bit too colloquial, less dry.

Comment: Note that in English at least, this sentence is going to be seen as false however you phrase it. Nobody is omnipotent, there must be *something* that is too difficult for you. Design a tower one mile high that's "not too dangerous" -- it's probably not impossible, but nobody has managed it yet (or, if I'm wrong and it's designed but not built, say 2 miles). "Design a building so beautiful that all who see it will weep for joy" is another example of a difficult brief. But perhaps the context makes it clear that you mean any difficulty within the bounds of normal architectural practice :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop - Precisely why I suggest a shorter version that removes the word "any" – see my comment below TRomano's answer.

Comment: I can design a building, no matter how difficult it might be.

Answer (score 5):

"levels" do not come in kinds.  A tier is a tier is a tier.

So you'd want to say:

**I can design a building of any complexity.**

Another way:

**I can design a building of any level of difficulty.**

Comment: In a slightly more "formal" register, *I can design **buildings of arbitrary complexity***.

Comment: @Fumble - Or (if we assume that designers of complex buildings can also design simple ones): ***I can design complex buildings.***

Comment: @J.R.: Well, linguists are fond of saying things like *[native speakers can generate]* [*sentences of arbitrary complexity*](https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=dtKeVbqZO8uq8wfbtJLADg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22sentences+of+arbitrary+complexity%22), and I have to admit that whereas that sounds perfectly "natural" to me, the same with ***any*** would sound more like the kind of "condescending" usage you might come out with if you thought the person you were talking to might not know the word ***arbitrary***.

Comment: For a resume (as this turns out to be) "of arbitrary complexity" is an improvement over "any", I think.

Answer (score 5):

In the following sentence you are suggesting that there are multiple *kinds* of *difficulty level*. There is only one *kind* of *difficulty level*, but there could be varying levels of difficulty.

> I can design a building of any kind of difficulty level.

In my experience, the following sentence would make the most sense.

> I can design buildings of any difficulty level.

This way you are not limiting yourself to one building (using *buildings* instead of *a building*) and you are conveying that you can build buildings with a lesser difficulty level as well as a greater difficulty level.

Comment: You could use "*I can design buildings of varying complexity.*" if you're worried about the situation presented in [@SteveJessop's comment](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/61462/i-can-design-a-building-of-any-kind-of-difficulty-level-looking-for-a-more-n/61471#comment117778_61462)